# Как в Java(android) сделать переключение картинок при нажатии

Tags: java, android

Хочу сделать, что бы при нажатии на картинку она менялась на другую, а та, в свою очередь, тоже менялась на другую и так много раз. Как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actuvity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"
        android:id="@+id/image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    ImageView image;
    int[] drawable={R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image4,R.drawable.image5,R.drawable.image6,R.drawable.image7};//картинки
    int i=0;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        image=findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){//ствиг картинки

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1)
                {
                    i++;
                    if(i==drawable.length){//если закончатся картинки начнет показывать сначала
                        i=0;
                    }
                    image.setImageResource(drawable[i]);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На Kotlin это может примерно так выглядеть. Но, конечно, вариантов можно несколько десятков придумать, в зависимости от реальной задачи, которую вы очень обще описали.

```
val imagesFromResList = listOf(R.drawable.image0, R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2)

imageView.setOnClickListener {
       imageView.setImageResource(imagesFromResList[Random().nextInt(imagesFromResList.size)]) 
}
```